# Android MapActivity onTap index always return 0

Tags: android, android-mapview

The onTap function in my MapActivity always return 0 no matter which element I click on the map. This is the onTap function:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int i) {

    OverlayItem item = myOverlays.get(i);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
    dialog.show();

    return true;
}

//myOverlays is a ArrayList<OverlayItem>
```

However. Every time the function runs, the index  (**i**) is always 0. I have confirmed this using both breakpoints and log debugging. This leaves me rather perplexed, because while using this function I am receiving the correct Dialog contents.

The **item.getTitle()** gets the appropriate title for the clicked element, meaning  the  item-object is correct, meaning **myOverlays.get(i)** is somehow able to get different objects, even though the index (**i**) is always 0. This is mindboggling.

Anyone care to enlighten me? Do you think this might be an issue related to the fact that the "clicks" are performed on an emulator?

*Thanks in advance.
Krys*

Comment: Post more code. It works fine on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess as you are not showing the code where you create the overlay and add items.

Probably you are adding multiple `ItemizedOverlays` and just one item to each of the overlays. Something like:

```
for(i=0; i<count; i++){
  MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(...);
  OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(...);
  itemizedOverlay.add(oi);
  mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
}
```

with the code above you will have multiple overlays, each one with one item in position 0.

For efficiency you should do something like:

```
MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(...);
for(i=0; i<count; i++){
  OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(...);
  itemizedOverlay.add(oi);
}
mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
```

with the code above, you will have only one overlay with multiple items.

Regards.

Comment: You are completely right, I can't see why i did not see that earlier. Thanks a bunch! :)